# Solving inhomogeneous ODE - arbritary function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, greens-function

I am interested in solving the inhomogenous non-autonomous ODE

$a \left(-b u(x_2)+\frac{\partial^2 u(x_2)}{x_2^2}\right)+c x_2 \left(-b u(x_2)+\frac{\partial^2 u(x_2)}{x_2^2}\right)-d\left(\frac{\partial^4 u(x_2)}{x_2^4}-2b\frac{\partial^2 u(x_2)}{x_2^2}+b^2u(x_2)\right)=f(x_2)$

The homogeneous solution is obtained as an Airy-function. The function $f(x_2)$ is also Airy function/exponential functional expression.

I am interested in solving the ODE above in general with an arbiratry function $f(x_2)$, similar as to with Greens functions for PDEs or Duhamels principle for special ODEs.

Has anyone any knowledge in this area, and can provide my with any advice?

I would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: I recommend you to simplify the equations, eg. definitely change $x_2$ to a one-letter variable. That way more people will be willing to look at it.  Furthermore i'm sure you have worked quite a lot on this problem, but try to type out more of this, so the people will see where you are stuck exactly. :)

Comment: Your linear ODE can be reduced to the equivalent form $u^{(iv)}+(c_1+c_2 x)u''+(c_3+c_4 x)u = f(x)$